# How to bind View and ViewModel in design-time if ViewModel requires parameters

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using the Caliburn.Micro framework.
On its [documentation page](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/design-time) it is said that:

You have to set a Desinger-DataContext and tell CM to enable its magic in your view XAML:

```
 <Window 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CaliburnDesignTimeData.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainPageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```

For this to work, the ViewModel must have a default constructor. If this isn’t suitable, you can also use a ViewModelLocator for your design-time ViewModel creation.

I want my ViewModel to be created with a parameter. How can I use the ViewModelLocator?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article about design time support for Caliburn.Micro.
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/19/caliburn-micro-design-time/

Basically you bind a ViewModel instance to d:DataContext with a ViewModelLocator (implemented and used as a converter) instantiating ViewModels through Caliburn's built-in SimpleContainer. That way you can set up your dependencies with the container and just create an instance of your view model using IoC.Get() and return it in your IValueConverter.Convert() method.

Comment: I've already found it, thank you. Do you think this is a good idea to define the IoC in the ViewModel project?

Comment: In the article, he instantiates a new SimpleContainer and reassigns IoC's GetInstance, GetAllInstances, and BuildUp generic delegates to the newly created SimpleContainer's matching methods. I believe you can reuse the already setup IoC on your AppBootstrapper (since it does that inside Initialize()) if you don't want to create a custom one.